# INSERT IGNORE & UPDATE VS INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Is there any different in performance between the following:

(1) Two statements

```
INSERT IGNORE...
UPDATE...
```

(2) One statement

```
INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Note that while this question ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541) asks about the difference between `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I'm more concerned about which of the above two patters (using one statement, or two) would perform better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` is faster than `INSERT IGNORE`, but failing with a duplicate key error is a lot faster

Comment: You can read this link too : 

http://www.eddieoneverything.com/programming/mysql-performance-tip-on-duplicate-key-is-faster-than-insert-ignore-but-failing-with-a-duplicate-key-error-is-a-lot-faster.php